# How to write in shorthand form if / else if / else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, shorthand, shorthand-if

Is there a shorthand for an if / else if / else statement? For example, I know there's one for an if / else statement:

```
var n = $("#example div").length;
$("body").css("background", (n < 2) ? "green" : "orange");
```

But how do I write the following in the shorthand syntax like above?

```
var n = $("#example div").length;

if (n < 2) {
    $("body").css("background", "green");
}
else if (n > 2) {
    $("body").css("background", "blue");
}
else {
    $("body").css("background", "orange");
}
```

Comment: `cond1 ? expr1 : (cond2 ? expr2 : expr3);` (parentheses not necessary in this case).

Comment: Your use of a ternary is appropriate in the first case.  But I would *not* use such a statement in the second case (where there are three or more possibilities) because it becomes much much more difficult to read later.

Comment: @Zeta that is exactly the kind of ternary I would avoid.  Nested ternaries are generally considered code smells/bad practice.

Comment: Agreed, nested ternaries are harder to read. One thing you could consider (makes the code more DRY and maybe easier to change later): have a `colour` variable, use if/elseif/else to set the `colour` variable, then only call `$("body").css(...)` once.

Comment: it gets called once, regardless, but it is less redundancy.

Comment: @nzifnab: Well, the question was about "how do I write it in shorthand". I don't really recommend it, but when you _do_ use this kind of notation, at least use a proper layout (which I can't use in this comment).

Comment: Sometimes the answer to a question should just be "You don't need to"  :P  Or do what @Shai suggested.  If you get into the habit of multi-conditional ternaries, you'll be in a world of hurt when you [try to use them in PHP](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30).  (But maybe that's more an indictment of the awfulness that is PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exist but it's highly UN recommended because it's pretty hard to read and maintain.

```
var n = $("#example div").length,
    color;

color = (n < 2) ? 'green' : 
        (n > 2) ? 'blue'  : 'orange';

$("body").css("background", color);
```

Comment: @GTSJoe like he said, it's NOT recommended.  I would argue that this is worse than just using `if` statements.

Comment: If you are going to use this approach, I recommend nesting each ternary operation so that it's readable. Ultimately, you're probably better with an if/else if/else once you get beyond a couple of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use a ternary for this, but I would recommend against (it's bad style).  You can also go with a switch statement:

```
switch(true) {
    case (n<2):
        $("body").css("background", "green");
        break;
    case (n>2):
        $("body").css("background", "blue");
        break;
    default:
       $("body").css("background", "orange");
}
```

But that's not really any better than just sticking with `if`

Answer (score 0):

Ternaries are fine if you use line breaks:

```
$( 'body' ).css( 'background',
      (n < 2) ? 'green'
    : (n > 2) ? 'blue'
    :           'orange'
);
```

Everyone has their syntactical preferences, but I think that's perfectly readable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no shorthand.

I'd also like to point out that the ?: operator is not a shorthand. One's an expression, the other is a statement.

If you'd like to make this code more concise anyway, I'd suggest getting rid of the braces:

```
if (n < 2)      $("body").css("background", "green");
else if (n > 2) $("body").css("background", "blue");
else            $("body").css("background", "orange");
```